# How to generate memory dump file in Xamarin for iOS application

Tags: xamarin.ios, heap-memory, dump

I am using Xamarin studio and working on Xamarin.iOS. I want to track some data whether it stays in memory after certain user actions or not. I am not able to find solution to do it in Xamarin. By generating dump file, I want to check for data entry in that file.